# How to collapse NA and merge multiple columns into one column

Tags: r, merge

I have a merged dataset looks like this:

```
    V3    V1.x               V2.x   V1.y                 V2.y   V982 V2163 
1  10075  Whitten Jamie L.   1225    <NA>                NA     2     2   
2  10421  Yates Sidney R.    1252    Yates Sidney R.     1252   2     0      
3  10520  Gonzalez Henry B.   445    Gonzalez Henry B.   445    0     0       
4  10573  Brown George E.Jr.  134    Brown George E.Jr.  134    0     0    
5  29584  <NA>                NA     Cubin  Barbara      254    0     0
```

I merged two datasets by matching V3. As you can see, both datasets have V1 and V2 variable and these two are not same.

I have two questions.

1) Is there any way I can merge two datasets without producing V1.x V1.y? I mean I wonder if there is any way I can have V1 which looks like this

```
V1
Whitten Jamie L.
Yates Sidney R.
Gonzalez Henry B.
Brown George E.Jr.
Cubin  Barbara
```

I used simple merge command like `merge(df1, df2, by=c("V3")`.

2) If I cannot merge these two datasets without V1.x and V1.y, then how can I collapse NAs and merge these two columns?

I searched other questions in the forum, and I found commands like
`cbind(data[1], mycol = na.omit(unlist(data[-1])))` 
 `na.omit(stack(df))` 
or `df2<-apply(df,1,function(x) x[!is.na(x)])`. But all of them don't work well. These commands seem to work when I don't have unrelated columns like V982 V3 or V2163. I don't know how to merge these two columns by collpasing NA with maintaining other columns like V982 V2163 etc.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Should your final dataset be only `V3`, `V982` and `V2163`? Or should it be `V3` `V1.x`, `V1.y`,`V982` and `V2163` and then a combined `V2.x` and `V2.y` such that the `NA`s from one are filed in with the `NA`s of the other?

Comment: perhaps you want `merge(df1, df2, by=c("V3","V1")`?

Comment: @MaratTalipov, that will not work (first, because you're missing a `)`,) because then you will lose those who have a `NA` or `<NA>` on `V1` or `V2` (if you were to add `V2` to your `by` statement.

Comment: Then, how about `df$V1 <- with(df,ifelse(is.na(V1.x),V1.y,V1.x))`?

Comment: By the time you've gotten to having `df`, you've already merged them. The goal would be to never have a `V1.x` and `V1.y`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is there any way I can merge two datasets without producing V1.x
>   V1.y?

You can try this solution, which will act on all columns that are present both in `df1` and `df2`:

```
d1 <- df1[df1$V3 %in% df2$V3,]
d2 <- df2[df2$V3 %in% df1$V3,]

m <- match(d2$V3,d1$V3)
z <- sapply(names(d1),function(s) ifelse(is.na(d1[,s]),d2[m,s],d1[,s]))
result <- cbind(z,d2[m,setdiff(names(d2),names(d1)),drop=F])
```

It selects rows from `df1` and `df2` with common values in `V1` column, and then  fills `NA` from the first data set using the corresponding value from the second data set for each other column.

> 2) If I cannot merge these two datasets without V1.x and V1.y, then
>   how can I collapse NAs and merge these two columns?

If you already merged your data, you can try this solution (it applies only to the column `V1`):

```
df$V1 <- with(df,ifelse(is.na(V1.x),V1.y,V1.x))
```

Comment: I think your first approach removes the last row (I could be wrong too as the datasets were not provided)

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to test it on realistic data sets.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your end product correctly, using `dplyr` it would be a simple:

```
df1 %>%
    select(V3, V982) %>%
    left_join(select(df2,V3,V2163), by=V3)
```

which gives:

```
     V3 V982 V2163
1 10075    2     2
2 10421    2     0
3 10520    0     0
4 10573    0     0
5 29584    0     0
```

Comment: I think he wants to coalesce the V1/V2 columns as well.  It looks like it's just an inner join on V3

Comment: My inner join (via `dplyr::inner_join`) looks just like OPs output. Am I missing an argument that would collapse V1 and V2?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am answering the second question as you provided the merged dataset.

The idea is to create a pattern ('pat') to specify the "prefixes" of the columns that needs to be collapsed.  Get the numeric index ("indx") of those columns with `grep`.  Remove the columns from the original dataset ("df") and create a new dataset "df1".  Loop the "pat" using `lapply`, subset the similar prefixed columns with `grep`, use `pmax` with `na.rm=TRUE` to get the the collapsed column, finally assign the list elements to new columns ("V1, V2") in "df1".

```
pat <- paste0('^V', 1:2, '..$')
indx <- grep(paste(pat, collapse='|'), names(df))
df1 <- df[-indx]
df1[paste0('V',1:2)] <- lapply(pat, function(x) do.call(pmax,
                           c(df[grep(x, names(df))], na.rm=TRUE)))
df1
#     V3 V982 V2163                 V1   V2
#1 10075    2     2   Whitten Jamie L. 1225
#2 10421    2     0    Yates Sidney R. 1252
#3 10520    0     0  Gonzalez Henry B.  445
#4 10573    0     0 Brown George E.Jr.  134
#5 29584    0     0     Cubin  Barbara  254
```

Or you can use `max.col` to find the "row index" of the non-NA values and get the elements with "row/column" indexing.

```
 df1[paste0('V', 1:2)] <- lapply(pat, function(x) {
            x1 <- df[grep(x, names(df))]
            x1[cbind(1:nrow(x1), max.col(!is.na(x1)))]})
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V3 = c(10075L, 10421L, 10520L, 10573L, 29584L), 
V1.x = c("Whitten Jamie L.", "Yates Sidney R.", "Gonzalez Henry B.", 
"Brown George E.Jr.", NA), V2.x = c(1225L, 1252L, 445L, 134L, 
NA), V1.y = c(NA, "Yates Sidney R.", "Gonzalez Henry B.", 
"Brown George E.Jr.", "Cubin  Barbara"), V2.y = c(NA, 1252L, 
445L, 134L, 254L), V982 = c(2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V2163 = c(2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("V3", "V1.x", "V2.x", "V1.y", 
"V2.y", "V982", "V2163"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: So this is taking the already made, bad merge, and collapsing the V1s and V2s?

Comment: Just read the question now more clearly.   Yes, I took the bad merge  data :-)  It seems to be a bit interesting problem rather than the usual `merge` type.  So, basically, I was answering the second question.